# My code for HackerRank Problem "Quee's attack II" runs slower than a similar looking code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and coding in general and I recently found HackerRank. I have been mostly doing easy problems until now.
Today, I saw the problem "Queen's Attack II" (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queens-attack-2/problem), wrote my code, and it didn't execute in time for some of the testcases. I optimized it best to what I could and then I went in the discussions, where I found a code from u/Arviy which follows basically the same algorithm as mine but the implementation was a bit different. But it ran just fine comparing all the test cases.

I also compared them to best of my knowledge, and tried to time different portions of code using "time.time() from import time". In the end, I got my code to pass the test cases but it still runs about 2x slower than the other code.

Variables setup -

```
n, k = 100000, 100000
r_q, c_q = 1, 1
obstacles = [[1000, 1000], [714, 169], [619, 264], [609, 274], [809, 74], [819, 64], [714, 264], [714, 74], [952, 569], [623, 471], [256, 985], [934, 419], [745, 280], [926, 189], [159, 859], [106, 912], [509, 894], [170, 402], [476, 238], [173, 546], [674, 438], [539, 597], [215, 724], [675, 975], [128, 814], [789, 162], [492, 142], [694, 384], [206, 253], [347, 625], [491, 147], [243, 639], [408, 401], [850, 293], [310, 901], [925, 147], [138, 471], [610, 203], [571, 658], [724, 762], [456, 908], [710, 842], [203, 321], [972, 254], [527, 214], [945, 750], [103, 561], [374, 947], [439, 716], [958, 504], [830, 182], [902, 635], [901, 158], [804, 532], [903, 957], [126, 916], [418, 485], [493, 385], [410, 247], [217, 712], [936, 340], [805, 645], [940, 430], [194, 148], [719, 247], [872, 928], [251, 231], [136, 240], [609, 860], [401, 230], [168, 759], [531, 907], [546, 927], [729, 590], [648, 912], [407, 793], [917, 256], [671, 489], [926, 874], [438, 467], [602, 462], [239, 328], [104, 510], [260, 739], [864, 741], [837, 493], [418, 345], [798, 754], [841, 710], [169, 365], [954, 389], [160, 496], [183, 108], [741, 796], [753, 682], [159, 324], [417, 306], [261, 509], [587, 194], [805, 907], [218, 204], [591, 389], [916, 894], [963, 103], [461, 689], [937, 520], [350, 730], [436, 208], [381, 617], [546, 361], [719, 512], [305, 794], [509, 820], [915, 570], [408, 420], [609, 973], [872, 710], [465, 409], [459, 427], [918, 847], [142, 943], [457, 364], [360, 273], [276, 289], [427, 537], [317, 475], [864, 832], [845, 639], [463, 520], [741, 617], [762, 734], [160, 804], [192, 739], [289, 715], [340, 826], [827, 872], [186, 836], [967, 639], [145, 137], [581, 147], [479, 897], [203, 960], [967, 691], [891, 680], [593, 651], [172, 257], [258, 325], [351, 859], [153, 801], [705, 589], [832, 832], [718, 864], [971, 652], [567, 561], [715, 729], [689, 821], [178, 891], [962, 408], [829, 639], [561, 413], [401, 261], [491, 952], [831, 741], [271, 471], [826, 312], [482, 317], [413, 769], [231, 561], [579, 735], [769, 916], [184, 586], [820, 208], [476, 298], [587, 157], [194, 642], [341, 647], [478, 731], [951, 620], [401, 912], [837, 358], [249, 349], [158, 201], [195, 968], [294, 132], [291, 193], [158, 480], [849, 761], [832, 157], [364, 809], [293, 526], [164, 865], [193, 429], [158, 520], [342, 574], [409, 815], [627, 765], [413, 316], [426, 508], [902, 620], [278, 385], [587, 342], [982, 812], [753, 721], [176, 192], [289, 729], [845, 729], [698, 205], [597, 378], [570, 251], [853, 742], [903, 126], [546, 172], [792, 491], [160, 926], [321, 597], [835, 356], [894, 207], [153, 807], [106, 372], [716, 105], [638, 281], [814, 597], [970, 926], [175, 943], [135, 642], [372, 142], [701, 980], [720, 184], [695, 491], [682, 354], [371, 246], [421, 574], [803, 108], [429, 687], [465, 953], [157, 385], [624, 893], [201, 896], [975, 295], [635, 348], [351, 659], [127, 109], [705, 852], [471, 327], [915, 750], [720, 637], [126, 358], [506, 690], [317, 923], [285, 725], [957, 406], [372, 810], [971, 170], [920, 452], [756, 743], [791, 158], [698, 835], [576, 470], [209, 329], [902, 948], [854, 249], [347, 780], [386, 215], [713, 130], [516, 760], [964, 374], [781, 340], [763, 402], [408, 824], [476, 642], [752, 320], [605, 185], [231, 745], [941, 962], [354, 760], [927, 426], [340, 164], [809, 720], [465, 152], [487, 280], [386, 690], [401, 605], [351, 517], [421, 120], [571, 870], [409, 581], [647, 268], [254, 168], [290, 687], [982, 452], [184, 813], [942, 726], [829, 856], [305, 874], [759, 456], [623, 930], [813, 984], [297, 432], [609, 397], [257, 921], [320, 375], [109, 570], [126, 210], [763, 189], [798, 708], [803, 368], [971, 631], [967, 791], [962, 850], [906, 201], [849, 403], [905, 389], [284, 231], [726, 275], [742, 562], [754, 948], [724, 481], [903, 168], [523, 231], [735, 452], [930, 149], [503, 950], [572, 473], [561, 967], [296, 281], [352, 283], [638, 856], [760, 602], [801, 170], [598, 417], [841, 965], [479, 485], [859, 916], [293, 248], [457, 791], [238, 462], [725, 943], [821, 372], [543, 901], [473, 507], [982, 723], [726, 394], [418, 350], [834, 150], [218, 437], [584, 290], [934, 271], [294, 895], [543, 671], [623, 784], [485, 478], [276, 643], [513, 136], [957, 407], [621, 340], [972, 817], [971, 291], [950, 315], [674, 315], [451, 982], [327, 829], [294, 154], [732, 601], [739, 352], [529, 495], [240, 720], [918, 387], [597, 715], [186, 716], [824, 875], [190, 852], [524, 328], [531, 753], [392, 985], [164, 849], [715, 864], [438, 935], [591, 946], [528, 690], [296, 560], [210, 102], [458, 148], [513, 615], [561, 324], [594, 451], [546, 159], [506, 473], [367, 107], [172, 230], [651, 629], [345, 628], [627, 425], [973, 940], [923, 914], [603, 437], [986, 684], [679, 230], [560, 204], [102, 578], [154, 863], [241, 153], [107, 152], [109, 530], [154, 849], [610, 175], [753, 213], [852, 279], [328, 287], [952, 832], [487, 904], [869, 519], [915, 809], [704, 657], [843, 871], [371, 351], [645, 963], [925, 638], [692, 623], [492, 786], [692, 708], [945, 658], [176, 736], [369, 547], [578, 812], [873, 763], [620, 418], [589, 209], [906, 418], [426, 976], [120, 451], [475, 735], [831, 746], [908, 270], [246, 721], [541, 120], [352, 286], [128, 826], [210, 431], [865, 687], [817, 576], [139, 907], [674, 491], [671, 396], [536, 604], [809, 396], [284, 817], [941, 841], [712, 370], [649, 931], [395, 689], [429, 249], [869, 218], [370, 730], [570, 140], [475, 136], [408, 509], [958, 294], [874, 847], [362, 807], [401, 301], [892, 204], [874, 365], [549, 780], [487, 146], [432, 293], [270, 901], [968, 891], [386, 642], [812, 801], [834, 860], [987, 237], [568, 894], [562, 271], [189, 704], [230, 928], [501, 905], [870, 189], [980, 421], [258, 126], [960, 402], [531, 852], [450, 374], [327, 840], [172, 405], [960, 680], [279, 532], [284, 829], [230, 701], [289, 218], [423, 580], [865, 895], [635, 129], [831, 809], [934, 568], [234, 901], [639, 976], [265, 256], [347, 194], [204, 863], [275, 748], [274, 973], [653, 793], [854, 873], [741, 917], [981, 653], [194, 642], [897, 538], [542, 914], [579, 701], [983, 459], [342, 857], [398, 650], [139, 973], [214, 216], [240, 684], [135, 529], [128, 780], [638, 493], [513, 240], [428, 168], [615, 423], [317, 560], [821, 791], [973, 724], [431, 729], [521, 267], [740, 231], [519, 706], [273, 897], [269, 902], [284, 362], [859, 912], [178, 352], [432, 513], [250, 248], [368, 614], [527, 319], [341, 125], [481, 543], [932, 412], [398, 428], [237, 648], [698, 870], [760, 352], [279, 749], [194, 607], [972, 973], [865, 136], [198, 750], [312, 871], [793, 159], [985, 923], [913, 635], [726, 813], [940, 948], [294, 364], [913, 482], [239, 127], [457, 390], [407, 679], [820, 327], [372, 867], [238, 794], [637, 546], [374, 857], [416, 130], [650, 650], [306, 926], [810, 823], [431, 378], [562, 593], [931, 715], [925, 256], [831, 718], [132, 837], [153, 571], [613, 436], [712, 817], [819, 527], [497, 947], [917, 629], [648, 548], [835, 164], [854, 324], [829, 859], [970, 694], [478, 860], [528, 204], [397, 925], [126, 457], [735, 593], [910, 532], [967, 930], [462, 718], [932, 867], [712, 827], [794, 534], [546, 162], [213, 941], [750, 980], [487, 761], [219, 263], [139, 870], [573, 932], [194, 609], [278, 839], [201, 305], [159, 576], [250, 857], [350, 607], [350, 674], [386, 702], [835, 561], [361, 817], [974, 187], [194, 984], [257, 201], [846, 973], [597, 361], [745, 658], [192, 397], [463, 738], [935, 913], [167, 572], [324, 210], [178, 641], [436, 890], [705, 795], [548, 721], [745, 104], [450, 612], [106, 613], [796, 908], [586, 374], [410, 827], [348, 561], [867, 573], [371, 493], [951, 438], [130, 302], [367, 156], [635, 926], [912, 346], [596, 732], [163, 850], [495, 725], [935, 849], [617, 789], [254, 952], [592, 748], [598, 514], [869, 215], [503, 906], [856, 865], [671, 893], [203, 298], [618, 168], [610, 207], [150, 634], [159, 906], [318, 867], [413, 412], [985, 134], [180, 280], [403, 781], [462, 370], [895, 567], [431, 876], [702, 583], [536, 514], [518, 364], [467, 697], [872, 853], [435, 245], [420, 134], [746, 109], [329, 278], [432, 389], [156, 875], [981, 312], [876, 361], [417, 269], [670, 762], [180, 405], [270, 319], [846, 345], [839, 863], [524, 418], [923, 704], [523, 489], [561, 913], [723, 369], [156, 620], [519, 164], [689, 354], [754, 324], [795, 459], [531, 931], [761, 187], [280, 289], [130, 907], [340, 173], [174, 846], [307, 456], [409, 729], [129, 418], [925, 465], [684, 563], [932, 582], [350, 471], [496, 547], [825, 875], [306, 245], [130, 678], [932, 264], [180, 109], [140, 520], [937, 247], [648, 954], [423, 957], [578, 254], [917, 514], [382, 539], [406, 405], [354, 486], [182, 392], [547, 124], [245, 760], [574, 187], [413, 618], [906, 976], [709, 931], [637, 891], [759, 253], [307, 684], [215, 168], [427, 683], [751, 132], [924, 182], [149, 528], [794, 564], [305, 386], [350, 497], [215, 963], [841, 102], [829, 130], [641, 149], [185, 527], [402, 804], [840, 740], [635, 641], [896, 573], [916, 987], [149, 209], [408, 904], [379, 528], [243, 863], [319, 721], [923, 942], [285, 523], [746, 429], [609, 645], [538, 528], [265, 321], [502, 615], [314, 432], [316, 349], [312, 493], [694, 260], [908, 541], [950, 630], [482, 234], [760, 548], [963, 345], [675, 569], [628, 591], [509, 485], [832, 610], [761, 480], [486, 841], [153, 841], [902, 750], [204, 905], [894, 539], [608, 137], [156, 721], [146, 435], [345, 647], [736, 239], [987, 346], [247, 319], [752, 568], [597, 796], [378, 180], [872, 601], [816, 853], [489, 583], [591, 506], [764, 603], [963, 261], [964, 702], [569, 910], [817, 649], [841, 487], [146, 609], [453, 468], [914, 684], [721, 216], [261, 703], [736, 687], [369, 927], [720, 640], [829, 741], [671, 987], [934, 248], [105, 368], [987, 714], [973, 672], [890, 840], [906, 786], [134, 351], [250, 394], [457, 540], [289, 237], [537, 104], [837, 437], [148, 504], [409, 654], [485, 895], [804, 706], [816, 943], [234, 156], [
149, 206], [340, 542], [840, 691], [652, 514], [526, 942], [732, 347], [280, 541], [806, 521], [523, 629], [835, 359], [176, 702], [370, 732], [975, 586], [674, 857], [852, 364], [869, 376], [719, 591], [182, 469], [175, 132], [691, 417], [124, 294], [103, 809], [912, 214], [597, 203], [549, 385], [896, 970], [463, 691], [508, 701], [360, 183], [650, 471], [169, 249], [824, 198], [734, 312], [679, 308], [927, 513], [261, 384], [873, 451], [876, 972], [265, 604], [746, 594], [652, 863], [127, 608], [692, 493], [675, 958], [564, 584], [742, 206], [816, 563], [906, 209], [931, 694], [608, 203], [580, 405], [631, 315], [129, 950], [596, 496], [826, 583], [365, 928], [842, 902], [508, 497], [903, 127], [381, 916], [458, 721], [685, 469], [720, 875], [351, 319], [178, 296], [830, 740], [547, 365], [823, 679], [507, 950], [297, 395], [217, 460], [186, 354], [405, 402], [245, 641], [975, 153], [758, 604], [390, 172], [936, 672], [823, 271], [590, 462], [470, 302], [680, 837], [371, 463], [605, 560], [248, 172], [856, 813], [152, 795], [254, 739], [705, 285], [576, 968], [270, 214], [539, 793], [376, 560], [175, 843], [341, 148], [423, 458], [631, 659], [428, 640], [935, 649], [946, 105], [950, 103], [807, 964], [976, 456], [230, 607], [460, 829], [915, 489], [164, 761], [815, 395], [784, 385], [417, 412], [708, 124], [247, 716], [869, 695], [179, 795], [504, 982], [175, 497], [215, 467], [284, 638], [638, 295], [248, 510], [481, 895], [715, 528], [527, 549], [478, 875], [716, 764], [327, 168], [456, 526], [170, 356], [249, 219], [602, 850], [142, 194], [821, 609], [104, 564], [948, 842], [851, 537], [375, 823], [408, 792], [195, 465], [490, 241], [981, 235], [175, 265], [679, 347], [293, 473], [406, 259], [156, 397], [784, 360], [306, 139], [258, 689], [369, 964], [386, 172], [971, 475], [893, 286], [438, 842], [690, 249], [183, 643], [374, 150], [256, 147], [432, 346], [508, 465], [324, 546], [584, 985], [164, 160], [395, 865], [381, 971], [928, 742], [862, 715], [850, 296], [491, 214], [753, 650], [814, 256]]
```

My first approach -

```
def queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles):
    direction_vectors = ((1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1))
    count = 0
    for i in range(8):
        r_q_temp, c_q_temp = r_q, c_q
        while True:
            r_q_temp += direction_vectors[i][0]
            c_q_temp += direction_vectors[i][1]
            if [r_q_temp,c_q_temp] in obstacles or not(0<r_q_temp<n+1) or not(0<c_q_temp<n+1):
                break
            count += 1
    return count
print(queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles))
```

Now in  u/Arviy 's code  -

```
def move_queen(n, updated_row, updated_col, r , c, obs):
    p = 0
    while True:
        r = updated_row(r)
        c = updated_col(c)
        key = (r - 1) * n + c
        if (c < 1 or c > n or r < 1 or r > n) or (key in obstacles):
            return p
        p += 1
    return p


def queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles):
    obs = {}
    for b in obstacles:
        obs[(b[0] - 1) * n + b[1]] = None

    p = 0
    dr = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0 , 1 , 1,1]
    dc = [0, -1, 1, 1, -1 , 0 , 1,-1]

    for i in range(8):
        p += move_queen(n, (lambda r: r + dr[i]), (lambda c: c + dc[i] ), r_q, c_q, obs)

    return p

print(queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles))
```

This code ran significantly faster than mine and I investigated and found that it was how he checked for obstacles, so I did the same it my code and it was immediate 10x speedup.
But still my code runs about 2x slower than u/Alviy 's code. **And I am unable to figure out why there was a huge speedup the first time and why my code is still slow?**

My updated code -

```
def queensAttack(n, k, r_q, c_q, obstacles):
    direction_vectors = ((1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1))
    count = 0
    obstacle_dir = {}
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        obstacle_dir[(obstacle[0] - 1) * n + obstacle[1]] = None
    for i in range(8):
        r_q_temp, c_q_temp = r_q, c_q
        while True:
            r_q_temp += direction_vectors[i][0]
            c_q_temp += direction_vectors[i][1]
            key = (r_q_temp - 1) * n + c_q_temp
            if key in obstacle_dir or not(0<r_q_temp<n+1) or not(0<c_q_temp<n+1):
                break
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com may be a better fit.

Comment: thank you for directing me there.